# Can't enable a UIButton on my titleBar

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I need to enable a button in my titleBar. And it this code doesn't enable it. Any idea why?

```
TitleBar.m
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *homeButton;

-(void) shouldShowHomeButton:(BOOL)shouldShow
{
self.homeButton.enabled=shouldShow;
}

OtherViewController
{
TitleBarViewController *titleBarController = [[TitleBarViewController alloc]init];
[titleBarController shouldShowHomeButton:YES];
}
```

I put a break point in *-(void) shouldShowHomeButton:(BOOL)shouldShow* and it is going in there. But doesn't update the button

Comment: The method name `shouldShowHomeButton` suggest what you're talking about is making the button _visible_, rather than enabling it. If that's the case then you need to set the button's `hidden` property to YES.

Comment: I need to enable it, kindly disregard the method name

Answer (score 0):

Here is the property of `enabled` and hope this will help you.

`@property(nonatomic,getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;

// default is YES. if NO, ignores touch`